# how to make fragment for every imageView

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have this

[image]

in `widnowManger` this 4 image without the layout under them 
i just want to know how to add fragment for every `imageView` when i click on it
and its will be in `service` not on Activity i am a beginner so any one can show me the way to add fragment when click on some image and pass the image `key` or `id` when click on it to fragment and when click on another imageView i dont want to destroy the last fragment and at the last i dont want to make 4 fragment for every image view because i dont know how much imageView i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ! use  **hide()** and  **show()**

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(this);
//……

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(fragment1,"f1");
    transaction.add(fragment2,"f2");
    transaction.add(fragment3,"f3");
    transaction.add(fragment4,"f4");

    switch (v.getId()){
             case R.id.imageView1:
                 transaction.show(fragment1);
                 if(lastFragment!=null)
                     transaction.hide(lastFragment);
                 lastFragment=fragment1;
                 break;
             case R.id.imageView2:
                 transaction.show(fragment2);
                 if(lastFragment!=null)
                     transaction.hide(lastFragment);
                 lastFragment=fragment2;

                 break;
             case R.id.imageView3:
                 transaction.show(fragment3);
                 if(lastFragment!=null)
                     transaction.hide(lastFragment);
                 lastFragment=fragment3;
                 break;
             case R.id.imageView4:
                 transaction.show(fragment4);
                 if(lastFragment!=null)
                     transaction.hide(lastFragment);
                 lastFragment=fragment4;
                 break;
         }
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: its good but i don't want to write case for every image view ... i mean if i have mabye 10 `imageView`  i must make 10 cases and the problem i dont know how much imageView i have mabye more than 10
i Vote up for you but try to solve the problem becasue i dont know how much ImageView i have

Comment: try use viewpager with fragment?